# Crosswalk extension not working in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, crosswalk-runtime, crosswalk

I am trying to make Crosswalk extension in iOS (Objective-C) for my own app which displays a website in Crosswalk runtime but it is not working. Following are the details:

1. Created CocoaTouch framework project at the root of my main project which is single page application.
2. Added the following code to the MyXWalkExtension.h file of my CocoaTouch framework project:

   ```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

   #import <XWalkView/XWalkView.h>

   //! Project version number for MyXWalkExtension.

   FOUNDATION_EXPORT double MyXWalkExtensionVersionNumber;

   //! Project version string for MyXWalkExtension.

   FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char MyXWalkExtensionVersionString[];

   @interface MyXWalkExtension : XWalkExtension

   @end

   @interface MyXWalkExtension ()

   - (void) jsfunc_myFunction:(UInt32*)callId message:(NSString *)myVariable;

   @end

   @implementation MyXWalkExtension

   - (void) jsfunc_myFunction:(UInt32*)callId message:(NSString *)myVariable {

   NSLog(@"MY VARIABLE: %@", myVariable);

   }

   @end
   ```
3. Added extensions.plist (couldn't find better way to display .plist content) to CocoaTouch framework project as follows:

   ```
   <plist>

   <dict>

       <key>XWalkExtensions</key>

       <dict>

           <key>xwalk.myxwalkextension.MyXWalkExtension</key>

           <string>MyXWalkExtension</string>

       </dict>

   </dict>

   </plist>
   ```
4. Added manifest.plist to the CocoaTouch framework project:

   ```
   <plist>

   <dict>

       <key>xwalk_extensions</key>

       <array>

           <key>item 0</key>

           <string>xwalk.myxwalkextension.MyXWalkExtension</string>

       </array>

   </dict>

   </plist>
   ```
5. Calling from javascript as follows:

   ```
   xwalk.myxwalkextension.MyXWalkExtension.myFunction('100');
   ```

I checked whether the above javascript code's block is executing or not & it is executing, but am not getting log in my xcode logging console. Because I think that the `jsfunc_myFunction` is not getting called from javascript. I don't know what am I missing or doing wrong. I am following [crosswalk project website](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/ios/extensions.html). I know that we don't need to extend Crosswalk runtime in case of Android where we can call Android native methods from javascript by providing a javascript interface, but in iOS it is not the case. So, I decided to extend Crosswalk runtime. The crosswalk project website is not much descriptive & detailed. Am I forgetting to embed the extension in my project, if yes, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[XWalkExtensionFactory register:@"xwalk.myxwalkextension.MyXWalkExtension" cls:[MyXWalkExtension class]];
//where xWalkView is XWalkView (Crosswalk's WebView).
[self.xWalkView loadExtension:[XWalkExtensionFactory createExtension:@"xwalk.myxwalkextension.MyXWalkExtension"] namespace:@"xwalk.myxwalkextension.MyXWalkExtension"];
```

I had to load my XWalkExtension & embed it into the app in ViewController.m.